# how to understand the present-participle "winding" in the following sentence?

Tags: present-participles

Here is the example,

> The long and winding road leads to your door.

I know the present-participle modifiers may indicate something undergoing a process or somebody doing something. But I think the "winding" here neither represents a ongoing process nor an activity and it indicates the mentioned road has a curving shape. The word seems to represent a state or quality. Is my understanding right? How should I understand the meaning by the present-participle form of the verb "wind"?

Comment: A ***winding road*** is a [*road that **winds its way***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22road+that+winds+its+way%22) along its allotted path, just like a ***river*** does. As opposed to (tired) ***people***, who are more likely to [***wend** their weary way*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22wend+their+weary+way%22) (home, or wherever the're going). But I think that ***wend*** relates to ***wander***, not ***wind***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To wind is to [turn repeatedly in different directions](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wind), as in

> The river **winds** through the valley.

> The path **wound** among olive trees.

[image]

The adjective *winding* originated from this verb, and, as you have correctly noted, describes something that has a curving shape; is twisting, or turning.